# Манипуляции с двумерным массивом

Tags: массивы

Дано массив 5*5, заполнен случайными числами. В каждой строке выбирается элемент с наибольшим значением, затем среди этих чисел выбирается меньшее. Указать индексы элемента с найденным значением.

Некорректно находит минимальный элемент и индекс этого числа.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   srand(time(0));
   int max, min;
   const int n(5), m(5);
   int matr[n][m];
   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
   {
       for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
       {
        matr[n][m] = rand()%100;
        cout << matr[n][m] << "\t";
       }
    cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
   cout << " Max number of each row\n " << endl;
   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)   //поиск мaксимальных чисел каждой строчки
   {
       max = matr[n][0];
       for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
       {
          if (matr[n][m] > max)
            max = matr[n][m];
            matr[n][0] = max;
       }
    cout << " Max num from " << n << " row " << "[" << max << "]" << endl;
   }
   min = matr[0][0];
   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)//поиск минимального числа среди максимальных чисел каждой строки
       for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
          if (max < min)
             min = max;

  cout << endl << "Min = " << min << endl;

   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)//поиск индекса минимального числа среди максимальных чисел каждой строки
      for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
          if (min = matr[n][m])
             cout << "Index:" << n << " " << m << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Отлаживать попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка вашей программы в том, что вы не правильно выполняете последние два цикла. 
В первом цикле вы нашли все максимумы и заполнили их в первый столбик. А во втором цикле, вы делаете. Сравнение последнего максимума с первым

```
 if (max < min)
         min = max;
```

Что является глупостью. Сложность вашего алгоритма О(3*n*m) я знаю ,что константы не учитываются, но эту задачу можно решить и за О(n*m)

```
int localMax;
int ans;
int x, y, localX, localY;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    localMax = m[i][0];
    localX = i;
    localY = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        if (localMax < m[i][j]) {
            localMax = m[i][j];
            localX = i;
            localY = j;
        }
    }
    if (i == 0 || localMax < ans) {
        ans = localMax;
        x = localX;
        y = localY;
    }
}
```

Постарайтесь переписать ваш код, чтобы он работал верно и понять, почему этот код работает тоже верно.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

const int WIDTH = 5, HEIGHT = 5;

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  std::vector<int> arr;
  for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) // Fill array with random values and print it immediately
  {
    arr.push_back(rand() % 100 + 1);
    std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    if ((int(i) + 1) % WIDTH == 0)
    {
      std::cout << '\n';
    }
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  int min_from_max;
  int min_from_max_index;

  for (auto i = arr.begin(); i != arr.end(); i += WIDTH) // Find max value in each line
  {
    auto max = std::max_element(i, i + WIDTH);
    auto index = max - arr.begin();
    if (min_from_max > *max)
    {
      min_from_max = *max;
      min_from_max_index = index;
    }
    std::cout << "Max " << *max << " having index: " << index << '\n';
  }

  std::cout << "\nMin from them is " << min_from_max << " that has index: " << min_from_max_index << '\n';
}
```

Компиляция и запуск:
    `g++ min.cpp -std=c++11 -o file && ./file`

p.s.
Кстати говоря. А что если 2 одинаковых числа, например 1 будут в одной строке? Мне сейчас попался такой вывод программы:

```
34      6       49      72      82
90      52      36      91      65
92      93      34      59      39
12      24      86      15      88
2       100     50      41      2

Min 6 having index: 1
Min 36 having index: 7
Min 34 having index: 12
Min 12 having index: 15
Min 2 having index: 20
```

Последняя строка имеет 2 2, но выбирается первое вхождение